# Specifying multiple servers in mongoDB connection string prevents it from connecting, but only specifying the primary server works

Tags: mongodb, exception, kubernetes, database-connection, connection-string

We have 4 mongoDB servers of which the first one is currently the primary with 3 replicas. If I specify all 4 servers in the connection string it fails to connect at all, but if I just specify the first one it connects fine. This is bad because if the first server fails, it will not be able to connect.

This works:
mongodb://login:password@server1:27017/admin?readPreference=Primary

This does NOT work:
mongodb://login:password@server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017,server4:27017/admin?readPreference=Primary

Exception:
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Connected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/server1:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/server1:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.

The service trying to connect runs on Kube.

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the mode to the connection string: replicaSet=myRepl